# How do you make an array in MIPS assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to make create an array in assembly language that uses an array of 10 elements to store 0-10, with each array location will hold a single integer.  Its' base address should be 0x47212000.  How would I do this?
From what I've learned, I should put the following code:

```
lui s0, 0x47212000        #This declares the array with the base address
```

After this, however, I'm stuck.  Do I need to make a loop to store the integers? How do I declare how many elements are in the array?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot `lui s0, 0x47212000`.  At best you can `lui s0, 0x4721` to get the higher 16-bits into the register.  But try @Eraklon's suggestion and then use `la s0, array`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to use assembler directives if your assembler has this.

```
.data 0x47212000
array: .word 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

If you want to wirte their values "manually" by a code then initialize them to 0.